# Why did the proced of Emacs not show the process on my win10 system?

Tags: spacemacs

My Emacs version is 26.1. The system is Microsoft Windows 10. When I run `M-x proced`, the buffer does not list the  proced used on the current system. What is this situation?

[image]

Comment: Hello, are you using plain Emacs, or the one with Spacemacs customizations?

Comment: Also, can you try running your Emacs without any initialization and loading of packages. You can see how to do that at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19194832/236007 After that, can you try `M-x proced` again? This way, you can identify if some configuration or package is interfering with `proced` mode.

Comment: Hello, I'm using Spacemacs customizations. When I started using `emacs-Q`, I tried `M-x proced` again, but it didn't show any useful information. I don't know where the problem was

Comment: It looks like Emacs uses `list-system-processes` and `process-attributes` in the background. Can you try evaluating first `(list-system-processes)` in your `*scratch*` buffer, and if it returns a list of numbers such as `(0 4 492 704 808 824 908 968 980 672 552 1124 ...)` can you then try to evaluate something like `(process-attributes 1124)` (replace `1124` with a number that you see in *your* list). This might show whether Emacs by itself can retrieve the process information from your MS Windows operating system.

Comment: Thank you. These two functions can return all the processes on my system and view the properties of the corresponding processes, but when I key in  `M-x proced`, I don't have a list of the current system processes.

Comment: Then it looks like Emacs by itself has no problem of communicating with MS Windows 10, and get the list of running processes. In this case, I suspect that something in the Spacemacs configuration might be interfering with `proced`, though I'm not sure what exactly at the moment. 

Comment: (proced) => (proced-update t) => proced-filter => proced-filter-alist                                 `(let ((proced-filter (quote all))) (proced))`                                                                            This is what I read in a post about Emac proced. I tried to run these commands to get the process of my current system in the proced buffer, but I could only get proced information every time Emacs was restarted. Once I killed the initialized proced buffer, I couldn't get proced information again (when I typed `M-x proced`).

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, but the documentation for `proced` states:

> Generate a listing of UNIX system processes.

Windows 10 is not a Unix-like system so my guess is that might cause some wonkiness.  Granted, I'm on Windows 10 and the 
command generates a listing of processes anyway.

- Maybe `list-processes` would be helpful?
- You could always "brute force" it and run the shell command to list all processes with `M-! tasklist`.

Comment: I've tried Emacs 27.0.50 on my Win 10 system, and for me it's the opposite: `proced` lists the running Windows processes, whereas `list-processes` doesn't list any process at all.

Comment: According to the documentation of `list-processes`: "Display a list of all processes that are Emacs sub-processes."

Comment: I think you meant `list-system-processes` (its documentation reads as "Return a list of numerical process IDs of all running processes.")

Comment: Thank you. I want to try to list the processes on the current system in emacs, but `list-proced` does not display the process information on my system.